# Attempting to retrieve a value from a JSON array in Groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I have a JSON object with an array (it is from the body of an HTTP response) that looks similar to the following:

```
{"people": [
    {
        "name": "john",
        "city": "chicago",
        "age": "22"
    },
    {
        "name": "gary",
        "city": "florida",
        "age": "35"
    },
    {
        "name": "sal",
        "city": "vegas",
        "age": "18"
    }
]}
```

I'm trying to retrieve the "city" or "age" values by looking for a "name." e.g., when "name" = "sal," I'd expect to get "vegas" to be returned if I was asking for "city" or "18 if I had requested for "age." I'm attempting to do this in Groovy.

Don't even know where to start with the code.  First time dealing with a JSON array. Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend starting by reading [Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html) documentation page. You will learn about the powerful `groovy.json.JsonSlurper` class that allows you to work with JSON documents efficiently.

When you create a JSON object representation with a method like:

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(rawJson)
```

You can access JSON document fields in the same way you access object properties. For instance, `json.people` will return you a list of people. Then, you can call the method like `find(predicate)` which returns a first result that matches the given predicate from a list. In this case, you can call something like:

```
def person = json.people.find { it.name == "sal" }
```

The `it` is a variable that keeps a reference to the object in the iteration process. It means that `find` iterates the list and searches for the first object that matches `it.name == "sal"`.

When you find the person associated with the name, you can extract `city` and `age` fields in the same way as you would access object fields, e.g.

```
println person.age // prints 18
println person.city // prints vegas
```

Here is the full example:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def rawJson = '''{"people": [
    {
        "name": "john",
        "city": "chicago",
        "age": "22"
    },
    {
        "name": "gary",
        "city": "florida",
        "age": "35"
    },
    {
        "name": "sal",
        "city": "vegas",
        "age": "18"
    }
]}'''

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(rawJson) // creates JSON object

def person = json.people.find { it.name == "sal" } // finds the first person with name "sal"

assert person.city == "vegas" // calling person.city returns a city name

assert person.age == "18" // calling person.age returns age of a person
```

To learn more about processing JSON documents with Groovy, consider reading the documentation page I attached above. It will help you understand more complex use cases, and it will help you gain confidence in working with parsing JSON documents using Groovy. I hope it helps.